# NextJS pass class from page to layout component

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to have a dynamic hero image (background image set by page specific class selector.)
My header is in the `layout` component.

```
function Layout({children}) {
  const pageName = children[1].type.name;
  const pageClass = pageName.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + pageName.slice(1);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <EmergencyBanner />
      <MainHeader pageClass={pageClass} />
      <MainNav />
      {children}
      <MainFooter /> 
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

The `layout` component is called in `_app.js` which is the entry point of the site and so it wraps every page.

```
function MySite({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>Title of My Site</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MySite
```

This seems to do the trick in Dev...the problem is post build for production, it works when landing directly on a page but when navigating to other pages, instead of the classes I expect, it either doesn't have a `pageClass` or it's simply a single letter for `pageClass`.

The css handling a background image for a specific page:

```
.home_header {
  background-image: url("../public/imgs/headers/img_i_want_to_use.jpg");
}
```

I was originally psyched to get this working in dev but quickly learned it's not a reliable method of passing a page level class up to a layout component for production.

I really would like to NOT HAVE TO move the header (& then also the nav because it's below it) from the layout, into every page. There has to be a better way.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can can pass and access the `pageClass` prop via the `Component` in `_app`. You can use this approach to independently pass props from any page component to _app.

_app file

```
function MySite({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout pageClass={Component.pageClass}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

layout file

```
function Layout({children, pageClass}) {
  return (
    <>
      <MainHeader pageClass={pageClass} />
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

page files

```
function HomePage() {
  return <>Home</>;
}

HomePage.pageClass = 'home_header'
```

*After you set or change the `pageClass`, you will need to refresh the browser to show the changes.*

Comment: how to pass the data from api with this? from the getStaticProps function?

Comment: would be nice to get updated answer for v13 appDir

Comment: Next 13 uses a [layout file](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts). This method isn't needed when using the app directory because you can fetch data in the layout and page, and Next SWR will dedup the request automatically.