# Pass page variables to layout in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm migrating my blog from Jekyll to NextJS and want to achieve the same functionality with the site layout.

The idea is to have metatags defined in a single layout file and fill values with variables that are defined on a page level.

I saw several solutions, one of them is to define metatags in _app.js as described here:
[NextJS pass class from page to layout component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977892/nextjs-pass-class-from-page-to-layout-component)

but from my understanding so far as a newbie in React/NextJS, it's better to utilize pageProps, but I can't figure out how to code it.
So far I have

_app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Layout from '../components/layout/layout';

export default function Blog({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (    
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>    
  );
}
```

layout.js

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Head from 'next/head';

import MainNavigation from './main-navigation';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
        <title>{children.title}</title>
      </Head>
      <MainNavigation />
      <main>
        {children}
      </main>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

HomePage.js

```
export default function HomePage() {   
   return <div>HomePage</div>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wanted to stick to the original code examples from the official documentation, so left layout as described in question, just

```
<Layout>
```

not

```
<Layout metas={pageProps.metas} ...>
```

So I just had to define props using getStaticProps:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  return { props: { title: 'HomePage' } }
}

export default function HomePage() {
  return <div>HomePage</div>
}
```

and then call it in layout as

```
{children.props.title}
```

not

```
{children.title}
```

The latter one would work if I just define a regular js variable in HomePAge.js as described in another SO thread I referenced. But I'm not sure if this approach somehow affects static website generation, so I decided to use NextJS built-in feature getStaticProps.

Comment: Hey, this has been of great help. However, when using TS and defining children as `{ children }: { children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] }` I get an error for `props` stating `Property props does not exist on element …`. Do you know my mistake / a fix here?

Comment: Sorry, didn't work with TS, can't help here.

Comment: This was actually useful. It works not only with getStaticProps but also getServerSideProps. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can take the props you want in `pageProps` and pass them to the layout component:

```
<Layout metas={pageProps.metas} ...>
```

And use them in the `<Layout />`:

```
export default function Layout({ metas, children }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>{metas.title}</title>
      </Head>
      ...
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: How can I define vars in HomePage? Tried to just add a line HomePage.title = 'HomePage'; to HomePage.js, but getting error: {metas.title} is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to chime in on how to do this using the NextJS Pages router rather than the App router, which is what I'm doing. Basically this isn't a NextJS issue at all, it's a React issue. `children` is simply a subset of the component's existing `props` attribute, so you can pass extra props in addition to `children` like this:

layout.jsx

```
export default function Layout(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <header>
                <h1>{ props.title }</h1>
            </header>
            <main>
                { props.children }
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

page.jsx

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <Layout title="Welcome to my homepage">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, ea?</p>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

If you're using Typescript, here's how to type it using the React-provided `PropsWithChildren` type  (via [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-children-prop-with-typescript/)):

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

interface pageProps {
    title: string
}

export default function Layout(props: PropsWithChildren<pageProps>)
```

Comment: Nice, but note - storing layout.jsx outside the app folder bypasses the app router's [Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) feature entirely, the header will refresh on each navigation without preserving state.

Comment: @rustyx True, but my example is specifically for the Pages router and not the App router. As far as I can tell if you wrap the top-level template in a `<Layout>` component there's no way to pass page-level metadata to the layout-level `<head>` component without re-typing everything manually, which defeats the purpose of the method

Comment: And anyway if you're using the Pages router Next.js will refresh the layout regardless